# Python - Tkinter run two threads concurrently

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I have two thread function at the moment, I want to create animated graphics in Tkinter as well as playing background music at the same time. I thought of using threading to achieve this.

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import *
from tkinter import *
import asyncio
import shutil
from time import *
import random as rd

from playsound import playsound


def graphicsThread():
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1080, 800
    ORIGIN = [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2]

    tk = Tk()
    tk.resizable(0, 0)
    tk.title("Name")
    screen = Canvas(tk, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, background="#A5B7BD")
    screen.pack()

    p1, p2 = [0, HEIGHT - 200], [WIDTH + 1, HEIGHT + 1]
    screen.create_rectangle(p1, p2, fill="#807E78", outline="")

    screen.mainloop()


def soundEffectThread(): playsound("assets/bgmusic.mp3")


Thread(graphicsThread()).start()
Thread(soundEffectThread()).start()
```

I have two threads, but they aren't running concurrently, the second thread with the background music only plays when I exit out of Tkinter.

How do I play background music as well as Tkinter **at the same time?**

Thanks

EDIT: Please ignore the useless imports

Comment: To be clear, the duplicate covers a completely different goal, but the fundamental problem is the same: You *called* the function you wanted to thread, you didn't pass it to the `Thread` constructor, so it runs synchronously to completion before the `Thread` constructor even gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is a blocking call, and the syntax is a bit wrong.
You should instead pass the addresses of your functions to the thread object, then your functions will execute in a separate thread.

For example

```
def func():
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Running...")
```

Running this now:

```
Thread(func()).start()
```

Will wait for the func to execute before returning.

If you instead use:

```
Thread(target=func).start()
```

The function will start in a separate thread.

You can read more here:
[Python Threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Good luck!